# Como efetuar a transição de um Jira através da chamada de um endpoint do Jira

Tags: transição, jira

Boa Tarde Pessoal,

Estou tentando efetuar a transição de um Jira através da chamada de um endpoint do Jira.
Pesquisando, eu [descobri aqui](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issues/#api-rest-api-3-issue-issueidorkey-transitions-get) que o endpoint seria esse:

```
POST /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/transitions
```

Conforme informado, o método para fazer essa transição de status do Jira seria POST.

Minha dúvida é saber qual o conteúdo do request. O que devo colocar no body?

Tentei isso:

```
{
   "transition": {
    "id": "11"
  }
}
```

Mas não funcionou. O Postman informou:

```
415Unsupported Media Type
```

Note que estou utilizando o `id = 11`, referente ao status `Work on it`.

Percebi também, que esse mesmo endpoint serve para o método GET (para recuperar todas as transições disponíveis) e para o método POST (para efetuar uma determinada transição de um Jira).

Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

O erro 415, geralmente está relacionado com o tipo da chamada que foi feita, quando o servidor não pode servir o request no formato solicitado.

Segundo a documentação que forneceu. Possivelmente faltou adicionar o header:

```
 --header 'Accept: application/json'
 --header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

Esses headers estão nos links fornecidos por você em sua pergunta.

Segue o código completo do link:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url '/rest/api/3/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/notify' \
  --user 'email@example.com:<api_token>' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "htmlBody": "The <strong>latest</strong> test results for this ticket are now available.",
  "subject": "Latest test results",
  "textBody": "The latest test results for this ticket are now available.",
  "to": {
    "voters": true,
    "watchers": true,
    "groups": [
      {
        "name": "notification-group"
      }
    ],
    "reporter": false,
    "assignee": false,
    "users": [
      {
        "accountId": "5b10a2844c20165700ede21g",
        "active": false
      }
    ]
  },
  "restrict": {
    "permissions": [
      {
        "key": "BROWSE"
      }
    ],
    "groups": [
      {
        "name": "notification-group"
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```